# sort list base on another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I'd like to sort b base on a's value descending order;

```
a = [2,1,5,3,4]

b = [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)]
```

For loop is working, but is there some way more faster?

result would be:

```
b: [(2,2),(4,4),(3,3),(0,0),(1,1)]
```